# Open another application's activity in the Same Task?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, task

For example, when I open F`acebook Login page` from an application that screen (`activity`) is loaded in the same `Task stack`.

In the same way, I want to open an activity of another application from my application, to be loaded in the same Task Stack, not starting New Task.

Normally, when we access other application we use "`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`", which creates new task.

But How do I load the other application's activity in the same Task ?

Targeted new application is not android built-in `Intent activities` (like `email, contact, call` etc.)

I am trying to open activity of my another application from one application.

**UPDATE**

I think I couldnt make it enough clear. I have application A and Application B installed in device, both apps made by me, not system built. Now I want to access main_activity of Application B from an activity of application A, and still remain in the same Task. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> But How do I load the other application's activity in the same Task ?

First, do not use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. This says that *you* do not want a new task.

Second, ensure that the activity that you are starting does not have a `taskAffinity` or `launchMode` that would interfere with this.

So, for example, `startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS));` will start the date-and-time Settings screen in your task. Most Settings screens have a `taskAffinity`, where this would still wind up in a separate task.

Comment: Can you check the update again please ...?? How do we remove taskAffinity ?

Comment: @Shasi: Quoting [the documentation for `android:taskAffinity`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#aff): "To specify that the activity does not have an affinity for any task, set it to an empty string."

Comment: @CommonsWare If I start an activity in another application which have own `android:taskAffinity` in manifest file. Is there any way or work around to start that activity in the same task of my app?

Comment: @NhấtGiang: I do not know of any, though this is an area I do not get into much, so I may be forgetting stuff... :-(

Comment: @CommonsWare I have encountered a problem in my app, I start an activity (using `startActivityForResult`) from another app. Because that activity is launched in a new task, so there is 2 tasks in the back stack.  I need to detect where user press back key to go back my app's task or they press home key, then go to recent apps and bring my task from background to foreground. Because in two cases, I always receive the same result in `onActivityResult` callback.

Answer (score -2):

for inbulit mail application :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("message/rfc822");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"test@gmail.com"});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "Content");
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "No email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: I am not attempting to open in-built apps with intent. I am typically trying to open one app from my another app, both my apps.

Comment: ok, I did not understand your question , furthermore I can suggest you ,may check this link  http://hmkcode.com/android-start-another-activity-of-another-application/